# How do I clean up badly-formatted x86_64 assembly?

Tags: assembly, x86-64, code-formatting

I have some assembly I want to clean up. It has all caps, inconsistent spacing and lots of unneeded newlines.

How do I beautify this x86_64 assembly code?

Comment: Some code-formatting tools exist, for example https://github.com/harryhanYuhao/aformatter is one attempt, currently pre-alpha quality according to the readme.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I don't know of anything specific to assembly, but the things you've mentioned can be accomplished with sed.

A couple of things to note:

- Mnemonics are matched by the regex `[A-Za-z0-9]+`. Off the top of my head I can't think of any mnemonics that include other characters.
- The upper half of the GPRs are matched by `r(8|9|1[0-5])(b|w|d)`?
- The byte GPRs (excluding r8b-r15b) are matched by `[abcd](l|h)|(sp|bp|si|di)l`
- The 16-, 32-, and 64-bit lower 8 GPRs are matched by `[er]?([abcd]x|sp|bp|si|di)`
- SSE registers can be matched with the regex `xmm(1[0-5]?|[0,2-9])`

For example:

```
# Replace tabs with spaces, then clean up lines of the form "op reg/imm, ..."
# N.B. without the /I option the match will be case-sensitive
sed 's/\t/ /g' <test.s | sed 's/^\s*\([a-z0-9][a-z0-9]*\)\s\s*\([a-z0-9][a-z0-9]*\)\s*,\s*/\t\1\t\2, /I'

# Lowercase all GPRs and SSE vector registers"
# I have chosen not to use the more compact patterns above in the interest of readability.
... | sed '/\([^a-z]\)\(AL|AH|AX|EAX|RAX|...XMM0|XMM1|...|XMM15\)/\1\L\2/gI'

# Lowercase all instruction mnemonics. More specifically, matches the first thing on every line except when it is followed by a colon.
... | sed '/^\s*\([a-z0-9][a-z0-9]*\)\([^:]\)/\L\1\2/I
```

Comment: That's nice, if I don't find anything that gets it all done I'll use this.Thanks! Still leaves me with uppercase instructions, I would just lowercase everything, but the labels are camelCase.

Comment: This is a bit crude, and I only cover some minimal cases to convey the idea, but it will do what you want: sed 's/\(ADD\|OR\|ADC\|SBB\|SUB\|AND\|XOR\|CMP\|AL\|AH\|AX\|EAX\|RAX\)/\L\1/g' <test.s

Comment: I guess I'll have to do something like that, but the problem is I use a few dozen of the SSE instructions, which look like PUNPCKLWD. Could probably get a list somewhere, and parse it to create a sed command that works. Will try that later.

Comment: I just realized that the pattern I gave in my example is wrong. After I correct it, you can use a similar pattern to match the mnemonics. That leaves only the registers, and while annoying, you can enumerate them all.

Comment: For byte registers, I think you're missing `[a-d]h` (the upper half of `[a-d]x`).

Comment: You can simplify `xmm(1[0-5]?|[0,2-9])` to `[xyz]mm(1[0-5]?|[0-9])`, can't you?  It's ok if both halves of the `|` match.  To handle MMX register, you could use `[xyz]?mm...`.  Hopefully nobody has ever used `mm15` as a symbol name, but if you're being strict then you should just leave it out.

Comment: It's in the markdown, but for some reason it's not rendering in the HTML. It should read [ABCD](L|H)|...

Comment: I surrounded the regex code with backticks - now it displays correctly.